# How to use regular expression character class properly?

Tags: java, regex, split

```
String a = "77*b+7-77/98+6";
String b[] = a.split("[*+-/]"); // works fine
b[] = a.split("[+/-  *]"); // gives pattern syntax exception because of   " * "
b[] = a.split("[*/+-]"); // works fine
b[] = a.split("[-*]"); // works fine
```

Please, help me to figure out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Regex square brackets `[]` denote a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). A character class can have two characters separated by a hyphen `a-z` to denote a **range** of characters.

This means that if the hyphen is used, and either end of the range is invalid, this is an invalid pattern. This hyphen must be escaped in this case, `\\-` in Java.

But, if the hyphen is used either at the **beginning** or **end** of a character range then the hyphen is not treated as a metacharater - because it cannot be a range. So your other patterns work because the hyphen is effectively escaped.

```
b[] = a.split("[*/+-]"); // works fine
                   ^ at the end
b[] = a.split("[-*]"); // works fine
                ^ at the start
```

The first expression has `+-/`, which is a valid range from `+` to `/` in the [ASCII character set](https://www.asciitable.com/), equivalent to the literal characters `+,-./`.

The errored expression has `/-`, i.e. the range from `/` to `SPACE`. `SPACE` is character `32` and `/` is character `47` so your range is `47-32`, the range is **backwards**.

Comment: While this answer might be technically correct, it is a bad suggestion to move the dash to the start or end of the class to fix the problem.  Why?  Because someone else may inherit your code down the road, and this could lead to a bug in the regex, if that person is not savvy enough to keep that dash in the beginning or end.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm explaining why the OPs patterns work, not providing a suggestion. The OP wanted to know why certain patterns error and why others don't. Your answer doesn't seem to explain that, whereas mine does.

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL "+" is ASCII character "43", "/" is "47". As "43 to 47" is a valid range, it works "fine". But it will accept the characters "," (44), "-" (45) and "." (46), too. Probably not what you want.